# How to randomly select multiple small and non-overlapping matrices from a large matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, random

Let's say I've a large N x M -sized matrix A (e.g. 1000 x 1000). Selecting k random elements without replacement from A is relatively straightforward in MATLAB:

```
A = rand(1000,1000);         % Generate random data
k = 5;                       % Number of elements to be sampled
sizeA = numel(A);            % Number of elements in A
idx = randperm(sizeA);       % Random permutation
B = A(idx(1:k));             % Random selection of k elements from A
```

However, I'm looking for a way to expand the above concept so that I could randomly select k non-overlapping n x m -sized sub-matrices (e.g. 5 x 5) from A. What would be the most convenient way to achieve this? I'd very much appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably isn't the most efficient way to do this. I'm sure if I (or somebody else) gave it more thought there would be a better way but it should help you get started.

First I take the original `idx(1:k)` and reshape it into a 3D matrix `reshape(idx(1:k), 1, 1, k)`. Then I extend it to the length required, padding with zeros, `idx(k, k, 1) = 0; % Extend padding with zeros` and lastly I use 2 `for` loops to create the correct indices

```
for n = 1:k
    for m = 1:k
        idx(m, 1:k, n) = size(A)*(m - 1) + idx(1, 1, n):size(A)*(m - 1) + idx(1, 1, n) + k - 1;
    end
end
```

The complete script built onto the end of yours

```
A = rand(1000, 1000);
k = 5;
idx = randperm(numel(A));
B = A(idx(1:k));

idx = reshape(idx(1:k), 1, 1, k);
idx(k, k, 1) = 0; % Extend padding with zeros
for n = 1:k
    for m = 1:k
        idx(m, 1:k, n) = size(A)*(m - 1) + idx(1, 1, n):size(A)*(m - 1) + idx(1, 1, n) + k - 1;
    end
end

C = A(idx);
```