# Efficiently find all n x m non-overlapping sub-matrices in a big matrix in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, matrix

I'm wondering if there's an efficient method of finding all non-overlapping sub-matrices in a matrix in Python.

Let's suppose I have the following matrix (which is in fact a list of lists):

```
def generate_matrix(filename):
    """ Generate a matrix """
    return [[x for x in y] for y in map_lines(filename)]
```

Which returns an example matrix:

> ```
> [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
> ```

or, nicely put:

```
 for x in generate_matrix(filename):
     print(x)
```

> ```
> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
> [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
> [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
> ```

How can I efficiently get all non-overlapping sub-matrices ? Is there any known algorithm / module in python which would apply for a matrix with, say, 2000 rows and 2000 columns ?

One knows that we can get each sub-matrix as follows:

```
def cont_in_sub_seq(lst):
    size = len(lst)
    for start in range(size):
        for end in range(start + 1, size + 1):
            yield (start, end)


def get_submat(matrix, start_row, end_row, start_col, end_col):
    return [i[start_col:end_col] for i in matrix[start_row:end_row]]


def get_all_sub_mat(filename, matrix):
    data = map_lines(filename)
    rows, cols = int(data[0]), int(data[1])

    for start_row, end_row in cont_in_sub_seq(list(range(rows))):
        for start_col, end_col in cont_in_sub_seq(list(range(cols))):
            yield get_submat(matrix, start_row, end_row, start_col, end_col)
```

However, the above doesn't give us the non-overlapping matrices, but all the possible combinations. Any suggestion is welcome !

I've only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32586267/6165050) when searching for specific information but matlab isn't quite my thing and that's a slightly different question.

---

As per comments, some additional restrictions:

- let's suppoose we're not treating `1x1` matrices.
- the output might come in any format
- as a constraint, let's suppose there're **only two possible values** in matrix (say `0` and `1`). So I'm looking for an efficient way to output **all** the sub-matrices which contain at least `x` cells of each of the values (`0` and `1`) and at most `y` cells.

I thought about generating all the solutions. But I don't think it's a good idea. The constraints for the only solution I want to generate would be to maximize the total number of cells in all sub-matrices (given the `x`, `y` constraints)

Comment: Can you give some example output?  Is there a required size (or some other constraint) for the output submatrices because otherwise there seems to be lots of possible outputs.  For example, one matrix that covers the whole, or many 1*1 matrices that each cover one element.

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz well, let's not treat `1x1` matrices. The output might come in any format you'd like. As a constraint, supposing that there're only two possible values in matrix (say `0` and `1`),  let's output the sub-matrices which contain at least `x` cells of each of the values and at most `y` cells. I'll update this in the question to make it clear :)

Comment: There is no such thing as a "non-overlapping submatrix" but there are "non-overlapping *collections* of sub-matrices". Are you trying to enumerate all such collections, or a single collection, perhaps one of maximum size? I suspect that once you clarify what you are trying to do you will be left with an NP-hard problem.

Comment: @JohnColeman by non-overlapping sub-matrices I mean: given my matrix example, and the constraints I recently added (suppose `x=1` and `y=6`) we can have the following solution: first sub-matrix between rows (0,2) and columns (0,1), second sub-matrix between rows (0,2) and columns (2,2) and third sub-matrix between rows (0,2) and columns (3,4). And of course, that's one solution. I want to generate all of 'em ^^

Comment: I know what "non-overlapping" means. My point is that it is a property of collections and not a property of individual matrices. Are you trying to enumerate the submatrices in a single solution or in all possible solutions? If a single solution, what criteria should be used in deciding which non-overlapping collection of submatrices to enumerate? For 2000x2000 there are possibly an astronomically large number of such collections.

Comment: @JohnColeman at first, I thought about generating all the solutions. But I don't think it's a good idea. The constraints for the only solution I want to generate would be to maximize the total number of cells in all sub-matrices (given the `x`, `y` constraints)

Comment: That makes sense -- but it seems like it might be a variation of the set-packing problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing hence my remark that I suspected that it was NP-Hard.